# Grid Column Sort Re-executes all my App code from the grid's store onward

Tags: rally

Best I can tell, sorting any column in one of my grids (which is configured with a store calling the LBAPI) re-executes all of my App code from the store's definition onward.  Is this expected behavior?  I would not think we would need to re-query the data used in the grid to sort it.

I defined the store as follows:

```
    // fetch the snapshot of all leaf level stories for the PI
    var ssPiLeafStories = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        context: {
            workspace: this.context.getWorkspace(),
            project: this.context.getProject()
        },
        pageSize: 10000000,
        fetch: find,
        rawFind: query,
        hydrate: ["ScheduleState", "c_" + this.gKanbanStateFieldName],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            load: this._processPiLeafStories
        }
    });
```

...sorting any column in the grid drives all of the App's logic from the function _processPiLeafStories and beyond (I think!).  Any suggestions on how to just sort the grid instead of re-running the bulk of the App would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Most grids are paged, so sorting would require re-querying the server for the data. In your store it looks like you are trying to get around this by specifying a giant page size but the grid behavior will remain the same. What are you trying to show in the grid? (You'll probably want to use limit rather than pageSize either way).

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  The grid shows all current snapshots of a selected Portfolio Item. If it must requery the data, I guess that is fine, but the entire App refreshes on me creating a less than ideal user experience.  Blame the pageSize vs Limit on Charles.